# Has anybody successfully upgraded your ionic cordova Hybrid app from android version 9.x to android Cordova version 10.x

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, version, hybrid

Im trying to upgrade the Android cordova version of the app from v9 to v10. But Im facing build issues.Has anybody else facing the same issue. I already tried and applied the prerequisites needed from this link https://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2021/07/20/cordova-android-10.0.0.html

Please input your ideas.

Comment: what error are you facing? please add screenshot or Error logs to your question.

Comment: i updated my app yesterday:
Step 1): Remove whitelist plugin: `ionic cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-whitelist `

Step 2): add android x plugin: `ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-androidx`

step3): add adnroid x adapter: `ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter`.

Comment: @NajamUsSaqib Thank you for these steps.. It worked.. Sorry I was caught up with other high priority tasks. So didn't get time to try this out until today.

Comment: Glad it helped you. would like to accept it as answer if i post it?

Comment: @NajamUsSaqib yes I would

Answer (score 1):

From what I have tried, seems like

`cordavo-plugin-androidx` is not required anymore since it does not support `cordova-andriod`: 10 and above.

Removing the `cordova-plugin-whitelist` and adding the `cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter` would suffice.

I am currently on cordova-android: 10.1.1.

If you are using local storage to save data, i.e. `cordova-sqlite-storage`, be sure to update it to 6.0.0 and add this line in your `config.xml` for migration of localstorage data in your app from `API 29 -> API 30`.

Uninstall: `ionic cordova plugin rm cordova-sqlite-storage`
Install: `ionic cordova plugin add cordova-sqlite-storage@6.0.0`
Install node package: `npm i cordova-sqlite-storage@6.0.0`

```
<preference name="AndroidInsecureFileModeEnabled" value="true" />
```

Last word, be sure to update your android studio SDK to support `30.0.3` as well, if not you might run into some build error.

Answer (score 0):

There is one version up, 10.1.0 which fixed some issue. Try out this one for the beginning

Answer (score 0):

Try these Steps to update your app:

Step 1): Remove whitelist plugin: `ionic cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-whitelist`

Step 2): add android x plugin: `ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-androidx`

step3): add adnroid x adapter: `ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter`

these will solve your migration issues.